# How to make CMake find real static libraries instead of dynamic wrappers?

Tags: cmake

I use `find_package` to include external library into my CMake project. Because I wanted to add support for static linking, I set `set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS FALSE)`. However, I still get libraries like `libglew32.dll.a` which are just wrappers that make dynamic linking easier. Instead, I want CMake to find `libglew32.a` which exists in the same directory. This is the [module to find GLEW](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/blob/3490d57344af611e1633a6179260ae7dfadd67b6/cmake/Modules/FindGLEW.cmake) I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always link to an exact library using the filename. Here are the flags you would use

```
 -l:[filename]
```

For cmake

```
 target_link_libraries(target :libglew32.a)
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing this on linux will use all static libraries

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .a ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES})
```

if you are building external libraries, usually i just include them in my target

```
target_link_libraries(myprogram
        ${LIBROCKET_LIBS_DIRS}/libRocketCore.a
        ${LIBROCKET_LIBS_DIRS}/libRocketControls.a)
```